# ¿Como puedo utilizar anotaciones en formato YOLO para segmentación en mi modelo personalizado?

Tags: python, machine-learning, yolo

Estoy trabajando en una red neuronal convolucional (CNN) para segmentación y clasificación, y tengo una función personalizada para reintroducir la última predicción para evitar parpadeos en los videos. También estoy considerando algunas mejoras, como utilizar varios cabezales convolucionales más pequeños en lugar de depender de uno solo. Sin embargo, tengo algunos problemas con la capacitación y quiero que la capacitación sea compatible con el formato YOLO.

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import layers

import numpy as np

def per_baipas(x):

# Stores the last prediction of dense_layer_8, if no prediction has been made yet, it passes an input composed of zeros

  global ulti_predic

  try:

    if(ulti_predic==None):

      ulti_predic=x

      return(ulti_predic)

    else:

      ulti_predic=ulti_predic

      return(ulti_predic)

    except:

        return(x)

# Define the input layer of the neural network:

input_layer = layers.Input(shape=(640, 640, 3))

# Original convolution and pooling layers:

conv_layer_1 = layers.Conv2D(filters=600, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(input_layer)

pooling_layer_1 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_layer_1)

conv_layer_2 = layers.Conv2D(filters=300, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(pooling_layer_1)

pooling_layer_2 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_layer_2)

conv_layer_3 = layers.Conv2D(filters=400, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(pooling_layer_2)

pooling_layer_3 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_layer_3)

# LSTM layer and connection to dense layer:

flatten_layer = layers.Flatten()(pooling_layer_3)

dense_layer_1 = layers.Dense(units=230, activation='relu')(flatten_layer)

dense_layer_2 = layers.Dense(units=150, activation='relu')(dense_layer_1)

ulti=per_baipas(dense_layer_2)

# Agregar capa LSTM:

con_l=layers.concatenate([dense_layer_2, ulti], axis=-1)

reshaped_layer = layers.Reshape((1, -1))(con_l) # Adds a time dimension

lstm_layer = layers.LSTM(units=240, activation='tanh')(reshaped_layer)

# Additional dense layers connected to LSTM and previous layers:

dense_layer_3 = layers.Dense(units=55, activation='relu')(lstm_layer)

dense_layer_4 = layers.Dense(units=30, activation='relu')(dense_layer_2)

dense_layer_5 = layers.Dense(units=60, activation='relu')(dense_layer_4)

dense_layer_6 = layers.Dense(units=75, activation='relu')(dense_layer_5)

dense_layer_7 = layers.Dense(units=150, activation='relu')(layers.concatenate([dense_layer_6, dense_layer_3], axis=-1))

dense_layer_8 = layers.Dense(units=150, activation='relu')(dense_layer_7)

ulti_predic=dense_layer_8

mask=layers.Dense(units=65, activation='relu')(dense_layer_8)

clas=layers.Dense(units=50, activation='relu')(dense_layer_8)

# Output layers:

output_layer_1 = layers.Dense(units=640 * 640, activation='sigmoid',name="segment")(mask)

output_layer_2 = layers.Dense(units=30, activation='Softmax',name="cals")(clas)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[output_layer_1, output_layer_2])

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer="Adam",loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics="accuracy")

This is an example of how training can be done:

import numpy as np

import gc

gc.collect()

#model.compile(optimizer="Adam",loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics="accuracy")

x_train = np.random.rand(1, 640, 640, 3)

y_train_1 = np.random.rand(1, 640 * 640)

#y_train_2 = np.array(1)

etiquetas = [1]

num_clases = 30

etiquetas_one_hot = np.zeros((len(etiquetas), num_clases))

for i, label in enumerate(etiquetas):

    etiquetas_one_hot[i, label] = 1

y_train_2=etiquetas_one_hot

model.fit(x_train, [y_train_1, y_train_2], epochs=100, batch_size=1)
```

¿Cómo entrenar con mascarillas y etiquetas en formato YOLO con mi modelo actual? ¿O necesito modificar mis capas de salida?

Intenté entrenarlo de esta manera, pero no funcionó:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
model.compile(optimizer="Adam",loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics="accuracy")
# Ruta de la carpeta que contiene los archivos .png y .txt
carpeta = "/kaggle/working/datasets/train/images"
c_lavels="/kaggle/working/datasets/train/labels"
# Crear listas para almacenar los nombres de los archivos .png y .txt
archivos_png = []
archivos_txt = []

# Iterar a través de los archivos en la carpeta
for archivo in os.listdir(carpeta):
    if archivo.endswith(".png"):
        archivos_png.append(archivo)
for ativo in os.listdir(c_lavels):
    if ativo.endswith(".txt"):
        archivos_txt.append(ativo)

# Ordenar las listas alfabéticamente
archivos_png.sort()
archivos_txt.sort()

# Crear una lista para almacenar las imágenes y los datos de texto
imagenes_y_txt = []

# Iterar a través de los archivos .png y cargarlos junto con sus archivos .txt correspondientes
for archivo_png in archivos_png:
    archivo_txt_correspondiente = archivo_png.replace(".png", ".txt")
    if archivo_txt_correspondiente in archivos_txt:
        ruta_png = os.path.join(carpeta, archivo_png)
        ruta_txt = os.path.join(c_lavels, archivo_txt_correspondiente)
        
        # Cargar la imagen y el archivo de texto
        imagen = np.array(Image.open(ruta_png))
        with open(ruta_txt, 'r') as f:
            texto = f.read()
        
        imagenes_y_txt.append((imagen, texto))

# Ahora tienes una lista llamada 'imagenes_y_txt' que contiene tuplas con cada imagen y su archivo de texto correspondiente
x=imagenes_y_txt[0][0]
y=imagenes_y_txt[0][1]
print(y)
lineas = y.strip().split('\n')
etiquetas=[]
# Inicializar las variables
valor = lineas[0][0]
etiquetas = []
etiquetas.append(int(valor))
num_clases = 30  # El número de clases en tu problema
# Convertir las etiquetas enteras en vectores one-hot
etiquetas_one_hot = np.zeros((len(etiquetas), num_clases))
for i, label in enumerate(etiquetas):
    etiquetas_one_hot[i, label] = 1
y_train_2=etiquetas_one_hot
x=np.array(x)
y=np.array(y)
model.fit(x, [y, y_train_2], epochs=20)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 59
     57 x=np.array(x)
     58 y=np.array(y)
---> 59 model.fit(x, [y, y_train_2], epochs=20)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:957, in TensorShape.__getitem__(self, key)
    955 else:
    956   if self._v2_behavior:
--> 957     return self._dims[key]
    958   else:
    959     return self.dims[key]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Una última cosa, es posible que algunas pestañas de mi código se hayan perdido cuando lo copié.